# How to run Simulink simulation on a workspace figure?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am plotting a 3d polygon in a figure, and then I want a Simulink quadrotor to fly on the same figure.

I have tried to "hold on", so it is keeping the same figure name on top of the figure, but the polygon is not displayed.

Below images show the polygon I draw at first, and then the simulated quadrotor flying.

[image: Polygon]

[image: Quadrotor]

Update-1: Here is the code, for the purpose of testing I am trying a very simple code:

```
figure('Name','Test-1','NumberTitle','off')
grid on;
hold on;

voxel([0, 0, 0],[0.5, 0.5, 10],'r',0.4);

axis([0 5 0 5 0 15]);

%x values of the path
xVals = [1 -2; 5 -1; 10 0; 15 1];
%y values of the path
yVals = [1 2; 5 1; 10 0; 15 -1];

sl_quadrotorCR;

sim('sl_quadrotorCR');
```

This is the main part of the code of Voxel that I am using (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3280-voxel):

```
function voxel(i,d,c,alpha);

%VOXEL function to draw a 3-D voxel in a 3-D plot
%
%Usage
%   voxel(start,size,color,alpha);
%
%   will draw a voxel at 'start' of size 'size' of color 'color' and
%   transparency alpha (1 for opaque, 0 for transparent)
%   Default size is 1
%   Default color is blue
%   Default alpha value is 1
%
%   start is a three element vector [x,y,z]
%   size the a three element vector [dx,dy,dz]
%   color is a character string to specify color 
%       (type 'help plot' to see list of valid colors)
%   
%
%   voxel([2 3 4],[1 2 3],'r',0.7);
%   axis([0 10 0 10 0 10]);
%

%   Suresh Joel Apr 15,2003
%           Updated Feb 25, 2004

switch(nargin),
case 0
    disp('Too few arguements for voxel');
    return;
case 1
    l=1;    %default length of side of voxel is 1
    c='b';  %default color of voxel is blue
case 2,
    c='b';
case 3,
    alpha=1;
case 4,
    %do nothing
otherwise
    disp('Too many arguements for voxel');
end;

x=[i(1)+[0 0 0 0 d(1) d(1) d(1) d(1)]; ...
        i(2)+[0 0 d(2) d(2) 0 0 d(2) d(2)]; ...
        i(3)+[0 d(3) 0 d(3) 0 d(3) 0 d(3)]]';



for n=1:3,

    if n==3,
        x=sortrows(x,[n,1]);
    else
        x=sortrows(x,[n n+1]);
    end;


    temp=x(3,:);
    x(3,:)=x(4,:);
    x(4,:)=temp;
    h=patch(x(1:4,1),x(1:4,2),x(1:4,3),c);
    set(h,'FaceAlpha',alpha);
    temp=x(7,:);
    x(7,:)=x(8,:);
    x(8,:)=temp;
    h=patch(x(5:8,1),x(5:8,2),x(5:8,3),c);
    set(h,'FaceAlpha',alpha);
end;
```

Update-2:

Here is the Simulink plotting code:

```
% Copyright (C) 1993-2014, by Peter I. Corke
%
% This file is part of The Robotics Toolbox for Matlab (RTB).
%
% RTB is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
% it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
% the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
% (at your option) any later version.
%
% RTB is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
% but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
% MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
% GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
%
% You should have received a copy of the GNU Leser General Public License
% along with RTB.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

function [sys,x0,str,ts] = quadrotor_plot(t,x,u,flag,s,plot,enable,vehicle)

% Flyer plot, lovingly coded by Paul Pounds, first coded 17/4/02
% version 2 2004 added scaling and ground display
% version 3 2010 improved rotor rendering and fixed mirroring bug
%
% Displays X-4 flyer position and attitude in a 3D plot.
% GREEN ROTOR POINTS NORTH
% BLUE ROTOR POINTS EAST

% PARAMETERS
% s defines the plot size in meters
% swi controls flyer attitude plot; 1 = on, otherwise off.

% INPUTS
% 1 Center X position
% 2 Center Y position
% 3 Center Z position
% 4 Yaw angle in rad
% 5 Pitch angle in rad
% 6 Roll angle in rad

% OUTPUTS
%   None
ts = [-1 0];

if ~isfield(vehicle, 'nrotors')
    vehicle.nrotors = 4;    % sensible default for quadrotor function
end

switch flag,
    case 0
        [sys,x0,str,ts] = mdlInitializeSizes(ts,plot,enable); % Initialization
    case 3
        sys = mdlOutputs(t,u,s,plot,enable, vehicle); % Calculate outputs
    case {1,2, 4, 9} % Unused flags
        sys = [];
    otherwise
        error(['unhandled flag = ',num2str(flag)]); % Error handling
end


% Initialize
function [sys,x0,str,ts] = mdlInitializeSizes(ts,plot,enable)
% Call simsizes for a sizes structure, fill it in, and convert it
% to a sizes array.
sizes = simsizes;
sizes.NumContStates  = 0;
sizes.NumDiscStates  = 0;
sizes.NumOutputs     = 0;
sizes.NumInputs      = 6;
sizes.DirFeedthrough = 1;
sizes.NumSampleTimes = 1;
sys = simsizes(sizes);
x0  = [];
str = [];          % Set str to an empty matrix.
ts = [0.05 0];

if enable == 1
    figure(plot);
    clf;
    %colordef(1,'none');
end
% End of mdlInitializeSizes.


function sys = mdlOutputs(t,u,s, plot, enable, quad)
global a1s b1s

% not quite sure what this is about -- PIC
if numel(a1s) == [0];
    a1s = zeros(1, quad.nrotors);
    b1s = zeros(1, quad.nrotors);
end

% vehicle dimensons
d = quad.d; %Hub displacement from COG
r = quad.r; %Rotor radius

for i = 1:quad.nrotors
    theta = (i-1)/quad.nrotors*2*pi;
    %   Di      Rotor hub displacements (1x3)
    % first rotor is on the x-axis, clockwise order looking down from above
    D(:,i) = [ d*cos(theta); d*sin(theta); 0];
    scal = s(1)/4;
    %Attitude center displacements
    C(:,i) = [ scal*cos(theta); scal*sin(theta); 0];
end

if enable == 1
    %draw ground
    figure(plot);
    clf;
    if length(s) == 1
        axis([-s s -s s 0 s]);
    else
        axis([-s(1) s(1) -s(1) s(1) 0 s(2)])
        s = s(1);
    end
    hold on;

    % plot the ground boundaries and the big cross
    plot3([-s -s],[s -s],[0 0],'-b')
    plot3([-s s],[s s],[0 0],'-b')
    plot3([s -s],[-s -s],[0 0],'-b')
    plot3([s s],[s -s],[0 0],'-b')
    plot3([s -s],[-s s],[0 0],'-b')
    plot3([-s s],[-s s],[0 0],'-b')

    %READ STATE
    z = [u(1);u(2);u(3)];
    n = [u(4);u(5);u(6)];

    %PREPROCESS ROTATION MATRIX
    phi = n(1);    %Euler angles
    the = n(2);
    psi = n(3);

    R = [cos(the)*cos(phi) sin(psi)*sin(the)*cos(phi)-cos(psi)*sin(phi) cos(psi)*sin(the)*cos(phi)+sin(psi)*sin(phi);   %BBF > Inertial rotation matrix
        cos(the)*sin(phi) sin(psi)*sin(the)*sin(phi)+cos(psi)*cos(phi) cos(psi)*sin(the)*sin(phi)-sin(psi)*cos(phi);
        -sin(the)         sin(psi)*cos(the)                            cos(psi)*cos(the)];

    %Manual Construction
    %Q3 = [cos(psi) -sin(psi) 0;sin(psi) cos(psi) 0;0 0 1];   %Rotation mappings
    %Q2 = [cos(the) 0 sin(the);0 1 0;-sin(the) 0 cos(the)];
    %Q1 = [1 0 0;0 cos(phi) -sin(phi);0 sin(phi) cos(phi)];
    %R = Q3*Q2*Q1;    %Rotation matrix

    %CALCULATE FLYER TIP POSITONS USING COORDINATE FRAME ROTATION
    F = [1 0 0;0 -1 0;0 0 -1];

    %Draw flyer rotors
    t = [0:pi/8:2*pi];
    for j = 1:length(t)
        circle(:,j) = [r*sin(t(j));r*cos(t(j));0];
    end

    for i = 1:quad.nrotors
        hub(:,i) = F*(z + R*D(:,i)); %points in the inertial frame

        q = 1; %Flapping angle scaling for output display - makes it easier to see what flapping is occurring
        Rr = [cos(q*a1s(i))  sin(q*b1s(i))*sin(q*a1s(i)) cos(q*b1s(i))*sin(q*a1s(i));   %Rotor > Plot frame
            0              cos(q*b1s(i))               -sin(q*b1s(i));
            -sin(q*a1s(i)) sin(q*b1s(i))*cos(q*a1s(i)) cos(q*b1s(i))*cos(q*a1s(i))];

        tippath(:,:,i) = F*R*Rr*circle;
        plot3([hub(1,i)+tippath(1,:,i)],[hub(2,i)+tippath(2,:,i)],[hub(3,i)+tippath(3,:,i)],'b-')
    end

    %Draw flyer
    hub0 = F*z;  % centre of vehicle
    for i = 1:quad.nrotors
        % line from hub to centre plot3([hub(1,N) hub(1,S)],[hub(2,N) hub(2,S)],[hub(3,N) hub(3,S)],'-b')
        plot3([hub(1,i) hub0(1)],[hub(2,i) hub0(2)],[hub(3,i) hub0(3)],'-b')

        % plot a circle at the hub itself
        plot3([hub(1,i)],[hub(2,i)],[hub(3,i)],'o')
    end

    % plot the vehicle's centroid on the ground plane
    plot3([z(1) 0],[-z(2) 0],[0 0],'--k')
    plot3([z(1)],[-z(2)],[0],'xk')

    % label the axes
    xlabel('x');
    ylabel('y');
    zlabel('z (height above ground)');
end

sys = [];
% End of mdlOutputs.
```

Comment: There are a multitude of reasons why this might occur. For instance, somewhere after your `hold on` there's something like a `clf` occurring (so the axis is cleared but the figure remains). You're most likely going to need to show us your code.

Comment: I have added the code that I am testing.

Comment: You need to use `hold on` after you create the axes not before.

Comment: That did not solve the problem, I still get the same output.

Comment: You haven't shown us the relevant code.  Somewhere in the simulation, code is being called to create a new axis, which is blowing away the axis (and the `hold on`) that you show in the code above.

Comment: Where do I find that code in Simulink?

Comment: It'll be called from somewhere in the model.  Without having the model nobody is going to be able to tell you where it is.

Comment: Found it and added it. Please take a look at it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am using "sl_quadrotor" model provided by Simulink, and up to this point I am just modifying at the model blocks level.

Comment: The problem (as suspected in my initial comment) is that the S-Function code that you've shown uses `clf` in a couple of places.  This "blows away" everything on the figure and resets its properties.  Unfortunately you can't just comment out those lines as the code regenerates new axes each time it's called in the simulation.  You'll need to modify the code to either a) allow you to pass in the location of your "tower" and plot it inside this S-Function, or b) modify the S-Function so that it doesn't re-create the whole visualization each time i.e. so that it just updates the copter location.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on it.